# How can use cut and when it encounters it goes to a new line?

Tags: shell, unix, cut

i have a file in which i need to use the cut command [image: this is the portion of file i need to edit]

i am using the command `cut -d "~"` but i need the server list from zlpv5489 to zlpv5494 
i need the below server list from the file

zlpv5489.vci.att.comzlpv5490.vci.att.comzlpv                   5491.vci.att.comzlpv6117.vci.att.comzlpv6118.                                                                                                          vci.att.comzlpv6119.vci.att.comzlpv5376.vci.a                                                                                                          tt.comzlpv5378.vci.att.comzlpv5379.vci.att.co                                                                                                          mzlpv5492.vci.att.comzlpv5493.vci.att.comzlpv                                                                                                          5494.vci.att.com

and not the rest

how can i use the cut command in this case ?

->below is the type of file

[image]

the output i require is thisoneandthis and not anything else

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, provide something we can copy and paste easily to test. Also, provide expected output

Comment: Are you more concerned w/ using cut (in which case, why?) or getting the job done w/ the most appropriate tool (which may not be cut)?

Comment: i have edited the ques with an example..i guess this will make my ques good

Comment: why do you keep adding images instead of text code? Your previous edit was more handy, because it allows people to copy the text and test locally. With the current one it is quite hard.